# Survey incorrectly asks for a France "department"

Tags: bug, survey-2017

If you live in France and take the survey, it asks you your *department* but displays the list of *regions*:

[image]

See:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Departments_of_France
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regions_of_France

You might want to fix this.

Comment: Apparently the Departments of France [wikipedia article] have multiple issues.

Comment: Some words about the context: in France, there are many layers of administration: the state, regions, departments, intercomunalities, municipalities. These subdivisions all care about the same policies and seldomly agree about what's to be done... It's called the administrative [https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mille-feuille](mille-feuille), just like the pastry. Frenchmen enjoy accuracy about both cooking and politics!

Comment: I didn't get any list of choice for the subdivisions of my country (China), which is much bigger than France... I didn't know if I had to input a province, a city of something else: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_divisions_of_China

Comment: Overall, I really don't see any relevance of this question. I'm guessing the survey was written by Americans. Since USA is a union of states, surely every other country in the world must be that too. Right?

Comment: @Lundin That's not a question, that's a bug report. The survey asks for incorrect information when you select 'France' as your country. Whether they fix it or not is no big deal, but I had to report it.

Comment: @ken2k I mean the relevance of having this question in the survey, not your question/bug report here on meta. Sorry, it wasn't clear.

Comment: @Lundin Ah, sorry I didn't understand your comment. Indeed I don't see either any value for this question. And that's not like the survey wasn't long enough already.